# Combine Customer and Purchase Date tables for latest purchase, but include nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I've got two tables, one where customer ID is store and another that stores each date they had a purchase on. I am stuck on keeping all new customers that don't have a purchase date yet when querying for the max purchase date for all customers.

CustomerTable:

| CustomerID | Full_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |
| 2 | Jane Doe |

PurchaseDates:

| CustomerID | Purchase_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11/21/2021 |
| 1 | 4/19/2003 |

I have set up a view in SQL that combines the two and queries for the MAX purchase date for each customer. The problem is that since I am using MAX, customers that have not purchased anything yet do not show up as they either do not have an entry in PurchaseDates table or their purchase_date field is blank.

My SQL View Code:

```
SELECT ct.CustomerID,
       ct.Full_Name,
       pd.Purchase_Date,

FROM   CustomerTable AS ct
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchaseDates AS pd
                    ON ct.CustomerID = pd.CustomerID
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   PurchaseDates  AS pd_latest
               WHERE  ( CustomerID= pd.CustomerID)
               GROUP  BY CustomerID
               HAVING ( Max(Purchase_Date) = pd.Purchase_Date))
```

The result in my example above yields only customerID 1 with the purchase date of 11/21/2021, but I'd like to also display CustomerID 2 with a null date for their purchase_date. Not really sure how to proceed apart from seeing that some have opted to replace all nulls with arbitrary days.

The end result should be

| CustomerID | Full_Name | Purchase_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 11/21/2021 |
| 2 | Jane Doe |  |

Appreciate the help

Comment: This is not because of `max` but because of your `where exists` - what are you expecting where no rows exist? Null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a single value from the `PurchaseDates` table so a simple correlated subquery is all you require:

```
select ct.CustomerID, ct.Full_Name, 
    (
        select Max(pd.Purchase_Date)
        from PurchaseDates pd
        where pd.CustomerId = ct.CustomerId
    ) as Purchase_Date
from CustomerTable ct;
```

Should more than a single column be required then you could *apply* the appropriate row:

```
select ct.CustomerID, ct.Full_Name, pd.*
from CustomerTable ct
outer apply (
    select top(1) *
    from PurchaseDates pd
    where pd.CustomerId = ct.CustomerId
    order by pd.Purchase_date desc
)pd;
```

Comment: Thanks Stu. If there's a case for other items coming from PurchaseDates table like what was purchased, does this method go out the window?

Comment: No, you could use an *apply* but that's not what you've asked in your question - @lamazibiji see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of the correlated subquery :

```
select * 
from (
(select Full_name,
  your_date,
  (select max(your_date) from PurchaseDates c where c.id=A.id ) as max_date
from CustomerTable A
LEFT JOIN PurchaseDates B ON A.ID =B.ID)) x
where (x.max_date = your_date) or your_date is null or max_date is null
```